# Different ways to pass XML via jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I'm facing a problem to get return value (content-type: "text/xml"). I'm able to get return value by direct access this URL:

`https://[domain_name]/myfolder/myapi/?xml=<xml version='1.0'><MyTasks><Search></Search></MyTasks>`

Please help me to correct these alternatives if it is wrong (called in HTML located in `MyFolder`) because it always alert 'Failed'.

```
$.ajax({
    type     : "GET",
    url      : "interface/?xml=<xml version='1.0'><MyTasks><Search></Search></MyTasks>",
    dataType : "text/xml",
    success  : function(msg){
        alert('Success');
    }
    error    : function(msg) {
        alert('Failed');
    }
});
```

or...

```
$.ajax({
    type     : "POST",
    url      : "interface/",
    data     : { xml: escape("<MyTasks><Search></Search></MyTasks>") },
    dataType : "text/xml",
    success  : function(msg){
        alert('Success');
    }
    error    : function(msg) {
        alert('Failed');
    }
});
```

Thank you.

**SOLUTION**

The interface has to be accessed by `https`, so I changed `url` param to absolute URL. I also have to use `"xml"` not `"text/xml"` as its `dataType`. It results Success, thank you.

Comment: do you get the `alert('failed');` ? and try `dataType:'xml'`

Comment: @3nigma Yes, I've tried to use 'xml', it keep alerts 'Failed'.

Comment: @iivel, XML string as parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simplify, I would do the following

Lets assume you are using a php script called script.php.

```
var xml_string = "<xml version='1.0'><MyTasks><Search></Search></MyTasks>";

$.get('script.php', {xml: xml_string}, function(){ //your success function
  alert('success');
}).error(function(){ //your error function
  alert("error");
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Does this take POSTs at all .. from your example, it looks like its setup for GETs..
Try this :

```
$.ajax({     
   type     : "GET",
   url      : "http://blachblahblah.com/abc.html",
   dataType : "text/xml",
   data     : { xml : escape("<xml version='1.0'><MyTasks><Search></Search></MyTasks>") },
   success  : function(msg){ alert('Success'); } ,
   error    : function(msg) { alert('Failed'); } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you use the dataType ?

What you want/need is contentType.

From api.jquery.com :

dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
Type: String
The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response.........

contentType (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8')
Type: String
When sending data to the server, use this content type. Default is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", which is fine for most cases. If you explicitly pass in a content-type to $.ajax().............

Hope this can help