# Calling PHP webservice method from Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've have created a PHP web service method

```
public function import_external_xml($importXml)
```

I want to allow a client to upload xml via my web service method. My web service is not on the same domain as the client. The client has a webpage with a button where he want to write some javascript/jQuery to upload the xml via my web service method.

How can he do this?

Web service method in server.php:

```
public function import_external_xml($importXml)
{ 
    echo 'import_external_xml';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: use ajax and from ajax call the function ,post your data through ajax and take it as function argument

Comment: Hi Arun, can you give me a example

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing using Ruby on Rails. But was sending data that was not in  xml format.
One important thing as you said that your webservice is not on the same domain, you will have to deal with CORS. You can get idea about CORS here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

You can refer this Post [JQuery JSON Calls To PHP WebService Always Runs "Error" Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20685949/jquery-json-calls-to-php-webservice-always-runs-error-callback?rq=1)

```js
function callPhpAPI(){
  var dataa = {"your_data":youdata};

  $.ajax({
            url : yourwebserviceurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data : JSON.stringify(dataa),
            contentType : "application/json",
            success:function(data)
            {
                if(data){ 
                  alert(data);   
                  //console.log("Data from Server"+JSON.stringify(data));
                }
                else{
                  console.log("Data is empty");
                } 
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
                alert('Error!  Status = ' + xhr.status + " Message = " + xhr.statusText);
                //console.log('Error!  Status = ' + xhr.status + " Message = " +  xhr.statusText);
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Hi Sachin, Thanks for your reply. But how can he the import_external_xml method?

Comment: I did not understand your question, but i think you are trying to ask how to call the php function import_external_xml, thats very well explained in the link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20685949/jquery-json-calls-to-php-webservice-always-runs-error-callback?rq=1

Comment: @SachinKadam he is trying to pass xml via ajax to his php function

Comment: Yes i got that, my reply was for "But how can he the import_external_xml method?" above.

Comment: Thanks arun. I'm sorry for my bad english. But yes, the client want to to send XML via my Webservice.

Comment: @SachinKadam : k ,i think you are confusing with this qusn,so i just try  help u to understand what actually he wants

Answer (score 0):

You can call your php function like this using ajax

```
xmlDocument = $("<wrap/>").append(xmlDocument).html();
xmlDocument = encodeURIComponent(xmlDocument);
```

then ajax

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'your_functions_address.php',
       processData     :   false,
   contentType     :   'text/xml',
     data            :   xmlDocument,

    success: function (obj, textstatus) {
                  if( !('error' in obj) ) {
                      yourVariable = obj.result;
                  }
                  else {
                      console.log(obj.error);
                  }
            }
});
```

i think you want pass xml via this ajax post , then you can refer this discussion

[post xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176548/different-ways-to-pass-xml-via-jquery-ajax)

also check  [this](http://www.virtualsecrets.com/jquery-send-receive-xml-json.html)

Comment: if i understand it than 'your_function_adresss.php' wil be 'http://mydomain/server.php' and the 'add' will be 'import_external_xml'?

Comment: Check the hyperlink in my ans