# submitting form data as xml to php page

Tags: php, xml, post

I am trying to submit form field data that should be converted to xml then posted to a php page that receives it using file_get_contents('php://input'). Can this be done using ajax/jquery? 
If yes, a friendly tutorial would be highly appreciated on how

1. form data is converted to xml format
2. converted data is posted
       to php page

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176548/different-ways-to-pass-xml-via-jquery-ajax

Comment: How can I convert the form data to xml format to post it?

Comment: as i know you have to fetch as json and you to convert in xml format.